# Unable to see OOTB web parts in the new experience SPO site page

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, new-experience

When I tried to a create a new page in SPO,I am getting the new site page [modern experience ?].So I added a page one.aspx n its saved in site pages library.
But i a stuck at how to add a new script editor/CEWP in this new expnce page?
when i edit the page, i am getting the all the new stuff -like office 365 stream, video,text, image, etc etc.
where are those existing OOTB web parts, such that i can customize with my own html,css, js.

[image: NO-OOTB-WP]

[image: WHERE_IS_OOTB_CEWP_SCRIPT_EDITOR]

Answer (score 1):

no javascript allowed in the new experience at the moment unless you create an SPFx app.

Comment: if this is the case, how can I modify my home page,using css, html, js. i wanna create a banner,some discretionary content , and a scrolling text similar to announcements, and an image slider. is there any work around for this.

Comment: You may check this web part. https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor